# Problems with laravel 5.4 password resets – sending e-mail

Tags: laravel-5.4, forgot-password

Problems with laravel 5.4 password resets – sending e-mail

After quite a few hours of research, I’m at a loss as to how to fix this fairly standard implementation of laravel 5.4.  I have added a multi-auth system, but I don’t believe that has an effect on the code being executed.  I am running the post route to send the e-mail…  But after that I get lost in tracing the code through.  Below, please find the error that’s been generated as well as other relating code.  I’m not sure if the error is in the user model, but it certainly could be.  Thank you for help‼!

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2443:Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()
1.  in Builder.php line 2443
2.  at Builder->__call('notify', array(object(ResetPassword))) in Builder.php line 1245
3.  at Builder->__call('notify', array(object(ResetPassword))) in Model.php line 1329
4.  at Model->__call('notify', array(object(ResetPassword))) in CanResetPassword.php line 27
5.  at User->sendPasswordResetNotification('c85443ddc950e30338975234e3ffcd10409efc8c43741e368b3f066398734fd5') in PasswordBroker.php line 70
6.  at PasswordBroker->sendResetLink(array('email' => xxx@yahoo.com')) in SendsPasswordResetEmails.php line 33
7.  at ForgotPasswordController->sendResetLinkEmail(object(Request))
8.  at call_user_func_array(array(object(ForgotPasswordController), 'sendResetLinkEmail'), array('request' => object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
9.  at Controller->callAction('sendResetLinkEmail', array('request' => object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
10. at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(ForgotPasswordController), 'sendResetLinkEmail') in Route.php line 203
11. at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
12. at Route->run() in Router.php line 559
```

---

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use App\User;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;
    public function __construct()    {        $this->middleware('guest');    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword; // DOES THIS NEED TO BE REFERENCED SOMEPLACE ELSE?

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question.  Well that the link below did not produce the same error, the result was the same.  I created another controller and invokes the same procedure called in the forgot password controller and everything worked seamlessly.

[Laravel 5.4 Password Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784010/laravel-5-4-password-reset)

```
use App\user;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class guestController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()   {        $this->middleware('guest');    }

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    public function sendPasswordEmail(request $request)
    {
        $a=user::where('email',Request('email'))->first();
        if(count($a)>0){
            $this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);
            return redirect('password/emailThankyou');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```